# Div keeps going to the top of the page, can't work out why

Tags: html

I've been setting up using a template, located at http://theimaginaire.com/v2 but for some reason the main div (with the circles and call to action at the bottom) keeps aligning to the top of the page and under the navigation bar.

Does anybody know why this may be?

Comment: Questions about code issues with link to affected website instead of code sample in the question body are not useful for other SO users. You're going to fix the issue on your website and/or it can become unavailable after some time. Any of these will leave your question meaningless to other users.

Answer (score 0):

Delete minheight..
and set following CSS:

```
position: relative;
padding-left: 15px;
top: 50px;
padding-right: 15px;
}
```

it works fine by me, when you set the top 50px (change at first with firebug)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your top two navigation / menu bars are aligned to the top, without concerning the flow of the document.

To fix this, apply

```
margin: 150px 0 0 0;
```

to

```
div.main
```

in the CSS file :)

Visual result: http://cl.ly/image/412m382p2d10/Image%202014-06-11%20at%2012.01.29%20PM.png

Answer (score 0):

Just delete this from custom.css

```
body {
    padding-top: 112px;
}
```

Change "body header" to this in your custom.css

```
body header {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
   box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   filter: none;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 1001;
}
```

Now you can set margin for your .main class.
Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that container with navigation is defined like this;

```
#header.colored > .container {
    height: 107px;
    margin-bottom: -92px;
}
```

so add this to your css;

```
.main {
   margin-top: 110px;
}
```